# Python Codewars: how to correctly decrease the number of zeros to be added to the new string

Tags: python

These are the CodeWar instructions:

> You will be given a number and you will need to return it as a string
>   in Expanded Form.
>
> NOTE: All numbers will be whole numbers greater than 0.

This is the code that I have.

```
def expanded_form(num):
    num = list(str(num))
    num = [int(i) for i in num]

    new_string = ''
    for each in num: 

        if each != 0:
            a = len(num) - 1
            new_string += ('%s' + '0' * a + ' + ') %(each)
            num.pop(0)
        else:
            num.pop(0)

    return new_string[0:len(new_string)-3]
```

When I run the function for the number 70304, I expect

```
70000 + 300 + 4
```

but I get

```
70000 + 3000 + 400
```

I thought that my code would iterate through each digit in `num`, and if that was zero, that it would shorten the list again. The next loop, `a` would produce the correct amount of zeros to be attached onto the digits 3 and 4. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I changed the function so that it was operating on integers instead of a string. Still same results though.

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: Here's a hint:  70304 = 7x10^5 + 0x10^4 + 3x10^3 + 0x10^2 + 4x10^1.  You can determine what order any integer > 0 is with `int(log10(n)) + 1`.  Doing this with strings feels both inefficient and prone to mistakes.

Answer (score 3):

**ANALYSIS**

I traced your loop in just one spot:

for each in num:
        a = len(num) - 1
        print num, [each], a
        if each != 0:
            new_string += (each + '0' * a + ' + ')
        num.pop(0)

Output:

```
['7', '0', '3', '0', '4'] ['7'] 4
['0', '3', '0', '4'] ['3'] 3
['3', '0', '4'] ['4'] 2
70000 + 3000 + 400
```

Two problems:

1. You change `num` while you're iterating through it.  This is fatal to your iteration.  `each` advances one position per iteration, so it's going to hit only the even-numbered positions in the string.
2. `each` is a single character; you compare it to an integer value of 0.  This will be true only for the null character.

**REPAIR**

```
def expanded_form(num):
    num = list(str(num))
    new_string = ''
    for i, each in enumerate(num):
        a = len(num) - (i+1)
        print num, [each], a
        if each != '0':  
            new_string += (each + '0' * a + ' + ')

    return new_string[0:len(new_string)-3]

print expanded_form(70304)
```

Output:

```
['7', '0', '3', '0', '4'] ['7'] 4
['7', '0', '3', '0', '4'] ['0'] 3
['7', '0', '3', '0', '4'] ['3'] 2
['7', '0', '3', '0', '4'] ['0'] 1
['7', '0', '3', '0', '4'] ['4'] 0
70000 + 300 + 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Prune's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44790543/13977676) is great but you can do it in one line too .
Im publishing it with your permission (i hope you give it to me) . if you dont want this please tell me in the comments to remove it .

```py
''.join([(each + '0' * (len(str(num)) - (i+1)) + ' + ') \
           for i, each in enumerate(str(num)) if each != '0'])[:-3]
```

or if you want a function .

```py
def expanded_form(num):
    return ''.join([(each + '0' * (len(str(num)) - (i+1)) + ' + ') \
           for i, each in enumerate(str(num)) if each != '0'])[:-3]
```